# Getting the following exceptipon "<begin>$L0->_Assoc_state was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF47" while executing future.wait()

Tags: c++, threadpool, future, predicate

I've created the thread pool using threads,mutex,condition variable and queue.Content of the queues are of type std::packaged_task<void()>.

```
std::vector<std::thread> m_workers;
BlockingQueue* m_taskQueue; 
for (size_t index = 0; index< threadCount; index++)
{
    m_workers.push_back(std::move(std::thread(&ThreadPool::WorkerTask, this)));
}
for (std::thread& thrd : m_workers)
{
    thrd.detach();
}
```

Main thread will create the thread pool and pushes the jobs to the m_taskQueue.There are scenarios where-in child thread will aslo push the jobs to the queue.While pushing the jobs to m_taskQueue i'm creating a future object for the task in order to track the completion of thread execution.

```
using job = std::packaged_task<void()>;
std::vector<std::future<void>> m_futures;
job ThreadPool::CreateTask(long jobNumber,Job\* job1 )
{
    int id;
    job j([id, job1]()
    {
    job1->Execute();
    });
    return j;
}
void ThreadPool::AddTask(Job* job1)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockGuard(m_mutex);
    m_jobNumber++;
    job j = CreateTask(m_jobNumber, job1);
    std::future<void> future = j.get_future();
    m_futures.push_back(std::move(future));
    m_taskQueue->Push(std::move(j));
    //SetEvent(m_jobAddedEvent);
}
```

In order to have sync between the main thread and thread pool.I'm using future in order to wait for the thread to complete the task.

```
for (auto& f : aCompiler->m_threadPool->m_futures)
{
    try
    {
        f.wait();
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e)
    {
    }
}
```

But i'm encountering following error
"Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.<begin>$L0->_Assoc_state was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF47".

Tried having the event mechanism between the thread pool and main thread didn't work.